# Looking for ideas on automatically arranging a set of objects (furniture) in a virtual room in AS3

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, algorithm

First of all, I don't want to visually arrange 3D models dragging them with the mouse, all I want is:

Given a room of certain dimensions (L,W,H) and given a set of elements like beds, chairs, etc (with L,W,H dimensions, of course) I want to automatically arrange those elements to take advantage of the space as much as I can. So I want to be able to put as much furniture as I can in a given room. At the end I need to represent the arranged items visually, inside the room.

My first thought was to use an array of items and sorting it with array.sortOn(["l","w","h"] Array.NUMERIC) and then define a gap between the objects and make the maths to put the objects one next to another, etc. but that isn't a good approach because some items may be placed on top of another ones (boxes of the same size, boxes on top of tables, etc).

I really don't have experience on 3D programming, that's why I'm asking for help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to "pack as many as you can" like what you literally said, or are you trying to make a "eye-pleasing" result? The first one is a NP-hard problem, and the second one is not something that requires a complicated algorithm.

Comment: And where does stated information come into play? Are you basing this off of just models or is there more data? i.e. are you wanting to make sure the model is flat on top and bigger/same so it can hold something? or can you flag it as "stackable" and give it a required height/width to fulfill?

Comment: Xavier Ho: The idea is: the user selects the furniture he/she wants to store and I need to arrange all the selected items in a way that optimizes the space, that way the user would be able to put inside the room as many objects as he/she can. And "optimize" would mean: stacking/piling some objects to save space, etc.

Comment: Dan Heberden: All I have is the dimensions of the objects and the dimension of the room, there's no 3d models, only raster images of the objects and the room (isometrics).

About the "stackable" flag, it's already done, I have a class called Item and it has such flag as well as a stackedItems method to retrieve the items on top of it. I have flags to know if the item allow items on top of it or if the item can be placed on top of another item, I have another flag to know if the is pileable (like boxes of the same size).

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is what's known as the ["Knapsack Problem"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) - if you can solve it, you get a Nobel Prize ;-)

Basically you're dealing with a reasonably small number of objects in your case, so you can probably get away with brute-forcing a solution. Otherwise spend some time at Wikipedia and read up on some of the various shortcuts to approximations that have been developed over the years.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the "Knapsack Problem". I didn't know it. I've been researching about it and it have been very helpful to know about it.